# SQL query to select from one table where either not in another table OR in that table with a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

For simplicity, say you have two tables...

```
users:
  user_id
  name
  age

clothing:
  user_id
  type
  color
```

How would you go about selecting all users who are 21 and either don't have any shirts at all or have shirts but don't have any red ones? My attempts thus far have looked something like...

```
SELECT users.user_id
FROM users LEFT JOIN clothing
ON users.user_id = clothing.user_id
AND clothing.type = shirt
AND clothing.color != red
WHERE users.age = 21;
```

I know how to do this query if I just wanted to select the entries that users that didn't have entries in the `clothing` table (`WHERE clothing.user_id IS NULL`), but I can't seem to extend that logic to this slightly more complicated case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.user_id FROM users
WHERE users.age = 21
AND users.user_id NOT IN
    (SELECT user_id FROM clothing WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL AND type = 'shirt' AND color = 'red')
```

It's actually simpler to identify all the people who have red shirts, and then say, "give me all the people *not* in that group." That being said, I think you actually need to break `clothing` into two tables: one table that just lists items of clothing, and another which links `user_id` to `clothing_id`.

Comment: Added a `NOT NULL` check since that seems to be possible in your table structure. That's another good reason why you need to break it into two tables- the existence of a piece of clothing has nothing to do with whether or not anyone is wearing it.

Comment: You can avoid the `user_id IS NOT NULL` check if you rewrite the NOT IN as NOT EXISTS. Other than that, I agree with your simplification of the condition. I came to the same conclusion a bit differently: a person must not have a red shirt or any shirt. But if they don't have any shirt, that includes a red shirt too, so it's enough to check for the absence of a red shirt to cover both cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT users.user_id
FROM users u1 LEFT OUTER JOIN clothing c  # outer join makes sure you get a user back.
ON users.user_id = c.user_id
where c.type = shirt AND
(count(select * from users u2 where u1.user_id =- u2.user_id LEFT INNER JOIN clothing c2 on u2.user_id = c2.user_id) > 0 OR 
c.color != red) AND
users.age = 21;
```

Comment: there is a typo `and where`

Comment: Without digging into these queries too far, neither of them would compile because of COUNT() in the WHERE clause. Aggregate functions can't be used in WHERE.

Comment: Removed first query that had that issue.  left 2nd one with only count in subselect.